# echo value of coalesced variable in yaml with azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have this variable in yaml

```
sonarVerbose: $[coalesce(variables['SonarVerbose'],false)]
```

and then I would like to output it which I do like this

```
- script: | 
   echo value is ${{variables.SonarVerbose}}
```

but it echo's [coalesce(variables['SonarVerbose'],false)] and not an expected 'false'.

Is this not possible ?

Comment: try `sonarVerbose: $[coalesce(variables.SonarVerbose, 'false')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that self assignment is not possible. As workaround you may use this:

```yaml
variables:
  sonarVerboseNew: $[coalesce(variables.sonarVerbose,false)]

steps:
- script: echo $(sonarVerboseNew)
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sonarVerbose;]$(sonarVerboseNew)"
- script: echo $(sonarVerbose)
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to solve this issue:**

You can replace your output script with the following script.

```
- script: | 
   echo value is $(variables.SonarVerbose)
```

**The cause of the issue:**

This issue arises because you are using compile time expression `${{ <expression> }}` instead of run time expression `$( <expression> )`.

The `${{ <expression> }}` will be evalusted before the yaml files executes. So the value is undefined at this point. It shows the expression itself, not the result of the expression evaluation.

Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.